# Regular Expression for Alphanumeric, Hyphen and Space

Tags: regex

I would like to have a regular expression that checks if a string contains only alphanumeric and hyphen.

This is my regular expression for alphanumeric validation only:

`var numericReg = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,20}$/;`

To which, I need to include hyphen and space too.

That means, value "`100-C09D10 A`" must also be possible to enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
^([-A-Za-z0-9]){1,20}$
```

or this

```
^([A-Za-z0-9-]){1,20}$
```

I think you are using JS. It should work. Check [here](http://regexr.com/). If you want to include space also then add a space in the character class

```
^([-A-Za-z0-9 ]){1,20}$
```

Always remember that `-` in character class is used for denoting the range usually. So if you want to include hyphen also you should either add it to the beginning or end of the character class or `\` it as suggested in other answer

Comment: In your question, you should add that there can be space as well along with hyphen as your test case contains space between last `0` and `A`. glad it worked

Answer (score 1):

Just add the hypen (and escape it!)

ie.

```
 var numericReg = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]){1,20}$/;
```

Comment: No, add it to the end ***or*** escape it. :) Also the parentheses are superfluous.

Comment: I done both - but better to escape it as well as this may be overlooked during maintaining the code and people add to the regex

Comment: If people who don't know anything about regex maintain code with regex, all ist lost anyway. I'm strongly against voodoo escaping (i.e. sprinkling backslashes "just in case"), it's entirely the wrong mindset to be in when working with regular expressions.

Comment: Your example has a space! @Tomalak - Better safe than sorry

Comment: The assumption that adding backslashes makes something safer is fundamentally flawed (case in point: it gave us `mysql_escape_string()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()`).